# Can we create usernames with @ symbol in wso2 5.6 and generate token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

```
curl -v -X POST --basic -u XKuBiDj2g_aJPHYMGfNNqlw4SpAa:pfBps6N27C6MKArvIG1KlOm_CYsa -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' -k -d 'grant_type=password&username=test_user@gmail.com&password=Welcome@123'  https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

> "error_description":"Users in the tenant domain : gmail.com do not
>   have access to application aip_default","error":"invalid_grant"}

```
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  Non-SaaS service provider. Application tenantDomain(carbon.super) != User tenant domain(aipsso.com)
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-17 20:24:39,065] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Error occurred while validating grant
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Users in the tenant domain : aipsso.com do not have access to application aip_default
       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler.validateUserTenant(PasswordGrantHandler.java:91)
       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler.validateGrant(PasswordGrantHandler.java:69)
```

In our wso2 5.6, some of the users have username@domainname.com and few other users have just usernames. can we generate OAuth token for both type of users?

Comment: `@` denotes tenant name, not email domain. You can try to enable emails as usernames (in carbon. xml)

Comment: Thanks For the quick reply.I have enabled email as username option. above error is gone.But  token not generated [http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked = false], [http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastLogonTime = 1539349047701] }
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-17 22:30:37,235] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener} -  Username :aipdevops1@aipsso.comInvalid Credential, ErrorCode :17002

Comment: Given correct password

Comment: Now i am not able create new user with @ symbol from wx2 console.sivabalan@gmail.com

Comment: It works changed javauser regex in usrman XML file thanks a lots